# How to keep uart RX interrupt enabled forever using HAL library on a STM32F1

Tags: c, stm32, hal

I see HAL provides the following function for receiving serial data with interrupts: `HAL_UART_Receive_IT(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart, uint8_t *pData, uint16_t Size)`
which basically setups rx interrupts and returns.
`HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback()` will be called once the amount of bytes received reaches `Size`.
HAL disables rx interrupts just before executing this callback
**Problem:**
The amount of incoming bytes will be variable (from 1 to ~100) and I need to put them into a ring buffer.
 
 
So I set `Size` to 1 and call `HAL_UART_Receive_IT()` again inside the callback to re-enable interrupts, and it works well if the board gets sent 1 or 2 bytes every now and then, but bytes are missed beyond that

My guess is they are missed because they arrive between interrupt disabling - enabling

Is there a way to keep interrupts running forever without overwriting HAL Cube generated code?
If not, what would be a clean way of overwriting the involved functions?

Is there something I'm missing that would avoid the need to find this solution?

Comment: This seems to be a known problem without an easy solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24875873/stm32f4-uart-hal-driver

Comment: Seems like DMA is the thing to write data from any peripheral to any memory buffer including ring buffer (DMA settings). And DMA interrupts is the easy way to handle all data, or even its half, at the receiving moment.

Comment: It is not really dependent to your question. But I think it might be worthy to try keil io drivers. Here is the link where you can find them for your mcu https://www.keil.com/dd2/pack/

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
__HAL_UART_ENABLE_IT(&huart2, UART_IT_RXNE);
```

Answer (score 2):

Circular buffer with DMA(for receiving)seems to be a solution for your requirement. This will always give RX interrupt(you have to just configure it once).

For similar requirements, usually I'm using a 1 byte circular buffer to handle data. Receive processing will be done in the ISR.

Answer (score 0):

You may try UART via the polling method instead of the interrupt method.
Polling method: UART won't return until it received the amount of data specified by the "Size" parameter.

Comment: Problem is "Size" is variable and my application is time critical, that's why I went with interrupts in the first place.
Got this working by editing HAL function `UART_Receive_IT` so incoming bytes go directly to the ring buffer and interrupts don't get disabled

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to put a special character to indicate the end of the massage, or you make your own protocol e.g. message header, message length , content , checksum
and you make the interrupt enabled for one byte and in the interrupt handler you store the received buffer until you find the last byte in the message and then you send to the main task in case of RTOS, or set a global flag.
By the way make sure to set the appropriate receive bytes size in

```
HAL_UART_Receive_IT(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart, uint8_t *pData, uint16_t Size);
```

inside

```
HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback
```

please check the return of `HAL_UART_Receive_IT` it may return error and also 
implement the

```
void HAL_UART_ErrorCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *UartHandle);
```

and check if there an error in the UART bus.